# How to keep Tesseract from inserting extra whitespace in words?

Tags: imagemagick, ocr, tesseract

I asked about this on the [Tesseract forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/Vv2ayOMyagg) already

Via Tesseract (and ImageMagick), I'm trying to find out the text of this
[PDF file](https://my.mixtape.moe/xfghop.pdf)

This is the section of the PDF that I'm working on, it's line #7 of the
PDF:

[image]

In this section, Tesseract is running into problems when trying to identify
the string *CONSTRUCTORA*.

It sees *CO NSTRUCTO RA*

It should see *CONSTRUCTORA*

Can anyone suggest any possible fixes for this?

This is the commandline sequence:

```
convert -density 600 my_pdf.pdf tmp.tif 
tesseract -l spa tmp.tif stdout > tmp.txt
```

These are the software versions:

```
~% tesseract --version 
tesseract 3.05.01 
leptonica-1.74.4 
  libgif 4.1.6(?) : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.3.0) : libpng 1.2.50 : 
libtiff 4.0.3 : zlib 1.2.8 
~% convert --version 
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-08-28 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org 
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC 
Features: OpenMP
```

Comment: Well, the kerning is terrible in the image, so that's not unexpected at all.  If it's consistently like that, it might be worth your while messing with the various settings. A guess would be to look at the settings around tosp_min_sane_kn_sp here https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/blob/master/docs/tesseract_parameters.md I don't have a lot of experience mucking about with tesseract settings. Not much more than knowing that they're documented for sh_t. You might get lucky, or you might be able to find a tutorial on the subject, or some old crust with exp in the matter, or a book. Good luck.

Comment: For this particular PDF, string, and software versions, the issue
is fixed by setting `tosp_min_sane_kn_sp=2.8`. The default value
seems to be 1.5. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Hey! You got so lucky!  You can provide an answer below with your code changes to close out this question. It may seem odd, but that's how we handle situations where the asker came up with a solution.  I think this may be of use to a few people in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For dealing with the irregular kerning of the PDF file, [Will](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1228/will) suggested tweaking the parameters around `tosp_min_sane_kn_sp` of the docs https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/blob/master/docs/tesseract_parameters.md

Setting `tosp_min_sane_kn_sp=2.8` solved the issue that was described in the question.

The new Tesseract invocation is the following:

```
tesseract -c tosp_min_sane_kn_sp=2.8 -l spa tmp.tif stdout > tmp.txt
```

The default value for `tosp_min_sane_kn_sp` seems to be 1.5. So far, I have only tested with values larger than 1.5.