# Configuring tesseract giving file not found error

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract, pytesser

I am extracting text from image(jpg file) using pytesseract. The extracted text has extra spaces.

```
Actual image text - Aditya
Output text - A di ty a
```

I am using the below code:

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(img,lang='deu',config='--psm 2')
```

I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47314024/how-to-keep-tesseract-from-inserting-extra-whitespace-in-words) solution over stackover flow. However when i am trying same i am getting error as below:

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(img),lang='deu',config='--psm 2 -c tosp_min_sane_kn_sp=2.8')
```

I am getting below error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\adi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tess_l74c0__v.txt'
```

Can someone please help me here.

Comment: Check if the file is really there and if it is, use `os.chdir(...)` to change your directory to the folder.

Comment: @Thornily The file is not there.

Comment: Then thats your problem.